How to derive Molmer-Sorensen gate Rabi frequency?
In the original paper by Molmer and Sorensen they derive this rabi frequency:

I understand the concept of a rabi frequency but i dont see how they got it here. from my understanding with second order perturbation they would need to calculate a propagator which is second order in the hamiltonian

and then calculate the overlap of the whole state with the gg or ee state, which should be sinusoidal. But in their paper there is no integrals, I am not sure how they got it

That expression looks like standard second order perturbation theory (see Wikipedia). Nothing really special in that sense. Have you read the wiki page on perturbation theory in quantum mechanics?
